# How to auto run a server when boot the Raspberry Pi

Tags: networking, server

I run into a question that I want to auto run a server in python when boot the Raspberry Pi every time.
I tried several methods but they all don't work for me. Assume my python file is

> /home/pi/Desktop/server.py

I tried to use crontab and wrote

> @reboot python /home/pi/Desktop/server.py &

But it doesn't work. I check the the server doesn't start.
I also tried to wrote in /etc/rc.local

> python /home/pi/Desktop/server.py &

Still doesn't work.

Only wrritten in

> /home/pi/.bashrc

works now. But it needs me to use ssh to remote login in and then start run the server.
What I want is just the server would auto run after I reboot the Pi, not needing to login in.
Anyway has ideas?

Comment: How do you run your script without autorunning it - or more importantly: does it include the shebang in the beginning `#!/usr/bin/python3`?

Comment: Just login in to my Pi, and run python /home/pi/Desktop/server.py in terminal

Comment: Forget about the shebang I asked for. Try adding the full path of the python interpreter in your crontab statement (most likely `/ usr/bin/python`. Cron is known to be peculiar about that. Note also that there is no need for an ampersand in crontabs (though that should not make it fail either).

Answer (score 4):

Since you call your script a *server*, I assume it needs network connection to run properly. Therefore you should consider running it via `systemd` with [`network-online.target`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html#network-online.target) as a dependency:

Create a file `/etc/systemd/system/my_server.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=my server
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/pi/Desktop/server.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and run:

```
sudo systemctl enable my_server
```

Don't forget to add a shebang line to your script as @Ghanima has explained in the comments.

Answer (score -1):

Try the next things:
1. Edit `/etc/rc.local`
2. At the end, add the next command: `sudo python /home/pi/Desktop/server.py &`
Let me know if it helps.

UPDATE:

Lets try a different method:
1) in `/etc/init.d/` folder create file (ex. `mypythonscript`)
2) give it execution permissions: `sudo chmod 755 mypythonscript`
3) in the file, add the next code:

```
#!/bin/sh
#/etc/init.d/mypythonscript

case "$1" in
  start)
    echo "Starting My Python Script"
    python /home/pi/Desktop/server.py &
    ;;
  stop)
    echo "Stopping My Python Script"
    killall python
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/mypythonscript{start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

4) After that run the next command:

```
sudo update-rc.d /etc/init.d/mypythonscript defaults
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. Everything in re.local runs as root user.